# Using hooks results in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal component that has to only appear once, when user opens up the website. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';

function WelcomeModal() {

    const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(true);

    function handleVisibility() {
        setVisibility(!visibility);
    }

    return (
        <div>
           <Modal
            title="Vertically centered modal dialog"
            centered
            visible={visibility}
            onOk={handleVisibility()}
            onCancel={handleVisibility()}
           ></Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

export default WelcomeModal;
```

I created a state called `visibility` which is initially true, after the user clicks on `Cancel` or `OK` on the modal, I try to change the visibility to false, so the modal closes. The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You're meaning to pass the `Modal` component those function **references**, not to **call** them during render. Remove the `()` from each - `onOk={handleVisibility}`. Calling the function during render updates state = infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mean to pass the `handleVisibility` function into the Modal component as the `onOk` and `onCancel` props but you are accidentally calling it with the parenthesis `()`.

This means that when the component renders for the first time, it calls the function, which changes the state, which triggers a rerender which then calls the function again and so on.

Comment: Yes, it worked like that, thanks a lot, I will pay attention to it from now on.